# How should I load data into RecyclerView from 2 different end points.

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I'm trying to find the best possible solution to load data from 2 different end points and show it into a RecyclerView.

I want to retrieve a list of items with retrofit from http://example.com/realestates. This will retrieve the list of 100 available properties in an specific location.

However, the response doesn't contain some information like the price and and address, therefore I need to all call: http://example.com/realestates/%id with every single id that I got from the previous api call.

I can populate the RecyclerView with the list obtained from the first api call but I'm having trouble thinking how I could make those 100 requests to retrieve the information and show it inside of the RecyclerView Item.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the structure of the JSON of both endpoints

Answer (score 0):

First, I would advise that you not take that approach if at all possible. The overhead of 101 api calls is going to kill the responsiveness of your app.

If you have any control over the api, or can get someone who does have control to make changes, it would obviously be much better to create a custom endpoint that returns all of the data in the equivalent of the first api call.

If you need to make 100 api calls, I would suggest using RxJava (which works well with Retrofit) to chain the 100 calls in response to the first one, and combine the results into something that can be used by your RecyclerView adapter.